# Ограничить показ контента (кнопка "more") по трем div-ам

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт показа дополнительного контента по нажатию кнопки `"More"`. У меня три главных `div`, в котором размещаются дочерние `div` и соответственно три кнопки `"More"`. Сейчас скрипт при клике на первую кнопку `"More"` скрипт подгружает все дочерние `div` подряд, вне зависимости от трех главных `div`. А когда все дочерние `div` показаны первая кнопка `"More"` пропадает, а остальные две остаются видимыми.

Можно ли (без изменения `html` кода) разграничить показ дочерних `div` в рамках каждого главного `div`, а кнопки `"More"` исчезали в зависимости от главного `div` в которых они находятся? Ниже приведу сам скрипт, думаю, вы поймете, что я имею ввиду.

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent .blog-cart-wrapper')),
  step = 2,
  item = 0;

data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
item += step;

document.querySelector('#more').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;

  if (tmp.length < 2)
    this.remove();
});
```

```css
#ccc {
  background: #9be8e1;
}

#bbb {
  background: #ec7878;
}

#ggg {
  background: #c1a5f7;
}
```

```html
<div id="ccc" class="tabcontent s-blog-card__container s-blog-card_container mt-none">
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;"><input type="button" id="more" class="heading-link-button" value="More" /></div>
</div>
<div id="bbb" class="tabcontent s-blog-card__container s-blog-card_container mt-none">
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;"><input type="button" id="more" class="heading-link-button" value="More" /></div>
</div>
<div id="ggg" class="tabcontent s-blog-card__container s-blog-card_container mt-none">
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;"><input type="button" id="more" class="heading-link-button" value="More" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли ... разграничить показ дочерних

Можно. Все операции с дочерними блоками надо выполнять в контексте их родителя. Например -

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent').forEach(parent => 
  [...parent.querySelectorAll('.blog-cart-wrapper')].slice(step).forEach(child => 
    child.style.display = 'none'
  )
);
```

Кроме того. Не используйте повтoряющиеся `id`. Выборка

```
document.querySelector('#more')
```

находит только один (первый) элемент с `id="more"`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent').forEach(parent => {
  let step = 2,
    item = 0;

  let data = [...parent.querySelectorAll('.blog-cart-wrapper')];
  data.slice(step).forEach(child =>
    child.style.display = 'none'
  );
  item += step;

  parent.querySelector('#more').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
    tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
    item += step;

    if (tmp.length < 2)
      this.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#ccc {
  background: #9be8e1;
}

#bbb {
  background: #ec7878;
}

#ggg {
  background: #c1a5f7;
}
```

```html
<div id="ccc" class="tabcontent s-blog-card__container s-blog-card_container mt-none">
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;"><input type="button" id="more" class="heading-link-button" value="More" /></div>
</div>
<div id="bbb" class="tabcontent s-blog-card__container s-blog-card_container mt-none">
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;"><input type="button" id="more" class="heading-link-button" value="More" /></div>
</div>
<div id="ggg" class="tabcontent s-blog-card__container s-blog-card_container mt-none">
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="blog-cart-wrapper">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;"><input type="button" id="more" class="heading-link-button" value="More" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно вместо  id="more" подцепиться за class?

Comment: @АннаМатвеева Да, так и надо.  И здесь тоже надо использовать `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но сама я это не внедрю ((

Comment: @АннаМатвеева: нужно верить в себя, всё у Вас получится, если пытаться.